# react-hook-form display error message on load

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using **[react-hook-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form/v/5.7.2)** to create form in my react app.

Everything working fine but I want to show all the error message while my form is loaded without clicking on the submit button. I checked the documentation but couldn't find any solution.

Any help & suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: We can't see what you see. Please show us the code and the error message. Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-custom-validation-8kuu7?file=/src/index.js it's in the example part inside the documentation

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the `mode` argument? https://react-hook-form.com/v5/api#useFormRef

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the mode property to `onChange` to get the error on the fly as the field value changes.

```
const { ...methods, trigger } = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' });
```

Call `trigger()` after the component mounted to validate manually when the form first loads with default data:

```
useEffect(() => {
  trigger();
}, [trigger]);
```

**V7**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V5**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: if there are re-render issues in your component, use setTimeout within useEffect and then call trigger..